# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate not being called in other class swift 4

Tags: swift, messageui

I have this code the problem its about didFinishWith result doesn't called and the app crashes. This is my code

**Note: In Objective C this code works fine because I create a strong reference in my class but I have a problem in Swift and I dont know how to solve this**

```
import Foundation
import MessageUI

class EmailCreator: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    // in other class I send this var to show email
    var viewToShow = UIViewController ()

    func sendEmail() {

        let mailComposeViewController = createMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
            viewToShow.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("Can't send email")
        }
    }

    func createMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposeViewController.setToRecipients(["example@test.test"])
        mailComposeViewController.setSubject("subject")
        mailComposeViewController.setMessageBody("test body", isHTML: false)
        return mailComposeViewController
    }
    //MARK: - MFMail compose method
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And here in other class I have this code to show the email:

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let email = EmailCreator()
        email.viewToShow = self
        email.sendEmail()
}
```

Comment: What's the crash and stack trace?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb6f4ebeb8)

Comment: Edit your question and add the whole thing there. I can’t use just that to help you.

Comment: Is there any logs in the console when it crash? Also, what's the line causing the crash? Also you are creating a `UIViewController` just to replace it, why not do `var viewToShow: UIViewController?` ? And then `viewToShow?.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I dont have a logs in cosole. The app show this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb6f4ebeb8)

Comment: The app show the view of viewToShow.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) after I press cancel the app crash because the delegate func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {} never is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes because you have the `EmailCreator`, a local var the delegate of `MFMailComposeViewController` as shown in your `func createMailComposeViewController`. By the time `MFMailComposeViewController` calls the `didFinishWith` method the `EmailCreator` is already `deinit`ed.
You can fix this by making your `EmailCreator` instance a strong property.

```
YourViewController: UIViewController {
    let email = EmailCreator()

     @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
        email.viewToShow = self
        email.sendEmail()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I used this code to improve the behavior lazy var viewToShow = MyVCToShowEmail () in the class EmailCreator :) now works perfectly